# App crash when opened by clicking on icon, but not through Play Store

Tags: android

I just received reports from some of my users who's running Lollipop, they're saying that my app would crash (with the message: App Stop Working) if they tried to launch it by clicking on my app's icon on their home screen. But if they launch my app from Google Play Store, the app would work without any problem.

What could be the cause of this? If it's any help, here's my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imincode.meniti

Btw there's no mention of any Crashes/ANR in my Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: You need to get a stack trace of the error from one of these users. Or use a crash reporting library so that they are reported to you automatically.

Comment: @Karakuri something like this https://github.com/ACRA/acra you mean?

Comment: Yeah the crash recording built into the Play Console is not very good. I would recommend Crashlytics https://try.crashlytics.com/ ACRA was the goto product a few years ago; but I would not recommend it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you need to get the stack trace. Google Developer console is not sufficient in tracking bugs in your app. It misses the vast majority of in app crashes. I think there are a few options here.

1) I would try replicating this with the emulator and see if you can get the stack trace there.

2) I would embed a high quality crash tracking library in your application to be able to better handle this in the future. Currently I would recommend using [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/). In my opinion they have the best crash reporting library on the market today. ACRA was very good several years ago before professional products came out, but does not hold up compared to modern trackers like Crashlytics.